# Operations on a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I'd like to know if I can get the matrix

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2\end{bmatrix}$$

given the matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix}$$

solely by applying matrix operations such as inversion, transposition, addition and multiplication.

This came up when I was deriving some formulas about $\nabla$ in curvilinear coordinates, but I'm not able to work it out. I could only see that if $\{(a_1,a_2,a_3),(b_1,b_2,b_3),(c_1,c_2,c_3)\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $B=AA^{\top}$. I want to generalize this result.

Comment: If you allow yourself addition, then you can literally just do $A+ (B-A) = B.$ I doubt that is what you are interested in. Similarly, if you allow multiplication, then you can do $AC=B$ and solve $C=A^{-1}B$ (which requires that $A$ is invertible). This is also likely not what you are interested in.

Comment: But the elements in $C$ would depend on the entries in $A$. I'd like to avoid this by allowing operations that involve only $A, A^{\top}, I$ (and maybe the canonical vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3$ if strictly necessary).

Comment: So you want $B=B(A, A^{T}, A^{-1}, (A^{T})^{-1})$?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Why not just diag($AA^T$)?

Comment: If you allow Hadamard products then $\;B=I\odot(AA^T)\;$

Comment: Let us write $B=C^2$ with $C$ diagonal with square roots over the entries of $B$. Going from $A$ to $C$ would be an orthonormalization process. So the question is : is (Gram-Schmidt) orthonormalization process amenable to a succession of linear operations ?....